# How can I keep the #-part of the url on load() with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

I load an html into a div called `right-body` using jQuery:

```
$("#right-body").load( "views/" + $(this).attr("page")+ ".html");
```

This reloads the whole page. Consequently, I lose the hash of the url. How can I keep the hash?

I've tried resetting it after the reload by:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
$("#right-body").load( "views/" + $(this).attr("page")+ ".html");
window.location.hash = hash;
```

but it doesn't work. `window.location.hash = hash;` seems to be ineffective.

Thank you!

Comment: You are trying to load a page in a page, again and again, is that correct?

Comment: @AndyNopparatAndyNopeBui I have a dropdown menu on my "main/mother" page which causes the jQuery load() into right-body. So if that is what you mean with "again and again", then yes.

Comment: $("#right-body").load( "views/" + $(this).attr("page")+ ".html" + hash)

Answer (score 1):

If the page is reloading after executing `.load()`, your value for the hash will be reset to `undefined`.

Rather than storing it in a variable, you could potentially use local or session storage and retrieve the hash once the page has reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by putting `window.location.hash = hash;` as a callback. 
. Might not be the best solution however as you can see the url flash from "#" to "#myhashparams"...

```
$("#right-body").load( "views/" + $(this).attr("page")+ ".html", () => {
window.location.hash = hash;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(typeof page === "undefined"){
    var page = "";
}
if(page !== ""){
    page = "views/" + $(this).attr("page")+ ".html";
}

$("#right-body").load(page);
```

**Notice!**
I do not recommend to use an id then, because it would repeat it again and again. So you need to change the id for your "child"-page.
Tell me if it doesn't work!